# React Native Google Login (Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occured)

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I am using **react-native-google-signin** version 2.0.0. I followed each and every step to make it working in Android.

I am using the both Debug and Release SHA keys in Firebase. In one of my other project google signin is working fine using debug key. I have generated the debug and released key correctly by using the commands as well as from Android Studio.

I tried each and every solution from Git and Stack but still getting the error in Alert box that "Error: A non-recoverable sign in failure occured".
I am stuck on this problem from last 3 days and still cannot be able to find out the correct solution.

Comment: Solved it !!
I dont know if its a firebase issue. Spent almost two days for this simple issue.
ADDED THE SUPPORT EMAIL ON FIREBASE AND IT STARTED WORKING
Firebase or the responsible authority should be informed about this. This is a major thing and it should be solved. It is nowhere mentioned on the documentation. If this could be added at troubleshooting info it could save time of many others. ,,,


have you tried this?

Comment: @GauravRoy Thanks for reply.
I already tried this step but the same issue.

Comment: @vikasdhiman, you can check here for the solution https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/issues/265

Comment: @NehaChauhan I tried each and every step the link shared by you. But, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem yesterday. Actually keygen command provides the wrong SHA keys. Also, I matched the keys via command line and Android both were same.

After that I copy the keystore file and convert online for getting SHA keys. I put the new keys in Firebase and it start working.